# python object that takes less memory and time and provides delivers the element when index is provided

Tags: python

I am very new to python, I want a list or something in python that takes very less space and time, Something very similar to the one given below, and I want to find an element using index.

For example:

If my length is m=5:

```
list=[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[0,4],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

When I perform this for m=8000, a lot of CPU memory is consumed and even it takes approximately 30 seconds to create the list.

Please find my attempt below:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
from time import time        

list1=[]
t0=time() 
for row1, row2 in combinations(range(8000), r=2):
    list1.append([row1, row2])
print "training time:", round(time()-t0, 3), "s" 

85% of my CPU
31.2 sec to run
```

I tried the same using collections.defaultdict both the memory usage and run time were low compared to list, I am aware that dict creates a lot of reference instead of storing the value.

My code and finding are below

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
from time import time        
dict1=defaultdict(list)
t0=time() 
for row1, row2 in combinations(range(8000), r=2):
    dict1[row1].append(row2) 
print "training time:", round(time()-t0, 3), "s"  

85% of my CPU
15 sec to run
```

From what I know the problem in dictionary is I can't access the data with index, Since I get my indexes from a different logic, Its essential for me to use something like lists that requires an index to fetch the element.

i.e from the above list I want like to fetch [1,2] when I do a list[4].

Is there anything other than list in python that allows retrieval of data provided index given and would at the same time occupy less space and take less time.

Comment: You certainly can access dictionary entries with an index. The index is just a key instead of a 0-indexed position. `data = {0:'hello', 1:'world'}` and `data = ['hello', 'world']` can both create `'hello world'` with `data[0] + ' ' + data[1]`.

Comment: Ya this I am aware of ,,  but i was wondering if there was any thing other then dict that i could use ,  so I dont have to do the addition

Comment: @Sam what addition? if your dictionary keys are numerical, you can index into them the same way you do a list. If you want the elements in a specific order (in case you want to iterate through them), use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of the normal dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are manipulating homogeneous continuous sequences (as you are here), then Python indeed imposes a huge overhead, as everything is an object in Python, and it's giving you flexibility you just don't need in this case.

In this setting, you might consider [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) - a low-level interface to continuous homogeneous buffers, or [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) - a higher-level library on top of it.